# dlang inheritance design for types passed between threads

Tags: oop, d

I'm writing a multithreaded program in the D programming language, but am pretty new to the language. There is a restriction on types passed between threads using the `Tid.send()` and `receive[Only]()` APIs in the `std.concurrency` package that they must be value types or must be constant to avoid race conditions between the sender and receiver threads. I have a simple `struct Message` type that I have been passing by value:

```
enum MessageType {
    PrepareRequest,
    PrepareResponse,
    AcceptRequest,
    Accepted
}

struct Message {
    MessageType type;
    SysTime timestamp;
    uint node;
    ulong value;
}
```

However, some `MessageType`s don't have all the fields, and it's annoying to use a switch statement and remember which types have which fields when I could use polymorphism to do this work automatically. Is using an `immutable` class hierarchy recommended here, or is the approach I'm already using the best way to go, and why?

**Edit**

Also, if I should use immutable classes, what's the recommended way to create immutable objects of a user-defined class? A static method on the class they come from that casts the return value to `immutable`?

Comment: using shared and lock gratuitously and you can be fine...

Comment: @ratchetfreak I think using `shared` or adding locks is overkill for message objects which will not be modified after they are created.

Comment: If you're sure the that the sender will not mutate the object later on, you can use `assumeUnique` when sending the class. You will not need to do any special handling with the construction.
http://dlang.org/phobos/std_exception.html#.assumeUnique

Comment: You don't need assumeUnique if it is a true immutable class and can be created as such.

Comment: @МихаилСтрашун, you are correct. Although sometimes the object isn't originally immutable, or needs to be mutated before being sent. That's why in these cases I prefer to use `assumeUnique`.

Comment: there is a problem that once you use assumeUnique, you no longer have a help from type system. It is fine if you have a temporary mutable local and want to call some processing function that expects immutable on it - guaranteeing that view on that data is really immutable for the duration of function call is easy. However, if you send such data to other thread, you are walking on a thin ice. Small accidental modification that will use initial mutable data after it was sent and you are in the world of undefined behavior with no compiler errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of a thumb, if you have a polymorphic type hierarchy, classes are the tool to use. And if mutation is out of the question by design, immutable classes should do the trick efficiently.

Great presentation from DConf2013 by Ali has been published recently : http://youtu.be/mPr2UspS0fE . It goes through topic of usage of `const` and `immutable` in D in great detail. Among the other good stuff it suggests to use 
`auto var = new immutable(ClassType)(...);` syntax for creating immutable classes. All initialization goes to constructor then and no special hacks are needed.

Comment: Works for me, and thanks for the link! I wish these kinds of new multiparadigm design patterns were a bit more discoverable.